# "Babylon has been shouted" reference meaning

Tags: idioms, terminology

I'm reading this Saunders story:
https://hungermtn.org/a-lack-of-order-in-the-floating-object-room/
and trying to understand what "Babylon has been shouted" is a reference to. Why Babylon?
Here is the sentence in question:

> He says, “Babylon has been shouted (gasp), in a sense…” and I hit the mike button without thinking and say, “Damn right!”

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's porn.

Comment: What does it mean / refer to? @YosefBaskin

Comment: Jeremiah 50:15, 50:46, or something?

Comment: @YosefBaskin I don’t think it’s porn.

Comment: @YosefBaskin your definition of porn is much wider than mine. The story is so opaque as to bore to tears but does not seem to be porn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Revelation 18 (KJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2018&version=KJV):

> 18 And after these things I saw another angel come down from heaven,
> having great power; and the earth was lightened with his glory.
>
> 2 And he cried mightily with a strong voice, saying, Babylon the great
> is fallen, is fallen, and is become the habitation of devils, and the
> hold of every foul spirit, and a cage of every unclean and hateful
> bird.
>
> 3 For all nations have drunk of the wine of the wrath of her
> fornication, and the kings of the earth have committed fornication
> with her, and the merchants of the earth are waxed rich through the
> abundance of her delicacies.
>
> 4 And I heard another voice from heaven, saying, Come out of her, my
> people, that ye be not partakers of her sins, and that ye receive not
> of her plagues.
>
> 5 For her sins have reached unto heaven, and God hath remembered her
> iniquities.
>
> 6 Reward her even as she rewarded you, and double unto her double
> according to her works: in the cup which she hath filled fill to her
> double.
>
> 7 How much she hath glorified herself, and lived deliciously, so much
> torment and sorrow give her: for she saith in her heart, I sit a
> queen, and am no widow, and shall see no sorrow.
>
> 8 Therefore shall her plagues come in one day, death, and mourning,
> and famine; and she shall be utterly burned with fire: for strong is
> the Lord God who judgeth her.
>
> 9 And the kings of the earth, who have committed fornication and lived
> deliciously with her, shall bewail her, and lament for her, when they
> shall see the smoke of her burning,
>
> 10 **Standing afar off for the fear of her torment, saying, Alas, alas
> that great city Babylon, that mighty city! for in one hour is thy
> judgment come.**
>
> 11 And the merchants of the earth shall weep and mourn over her; for
> no man buyeth their merchandise any more:
>
> 12 The merchandise of gold, and silver, and precious stones, and of
> pearls, and fine linen, and purple, and silk, and scarlet, and all
> thyine wood, and all manner vessels of ivory, and all manner vessels
> of most precious wood, and of brass, and iron, and marble,
>
> 13 And cinnamon, and odours, and ointments, and frankincense, and
> wine, and oil, and fine flour, and wheat, and beasts, and sheep, and
> horses, and chariots, and slaves, and souls of men.
>
> 14 And the fruits that thy soul lusted after are departed from thee,
> and all things which were dainty and goodly are departed from thee,
> and thou shalt find them no more at all.
>
> 15 The merchants of these things, which were made rich by her, shall
> stand afar off for the fear of her torment, weeping and wailing,
>
> 16 And saying, Alas, alas that great city, that was clothed in fine
> linen, and purple, and scarlet, and decked with gold, and precious
> stones, and pearls!
>
> 17 For in one hour so great riches is come to nought. And every
> shipmaster, and all the company in ships, and sailors, and as many as
> trade by sea, stood afar off,
>
> 18 And cried when they saw the smoke of her burning, saying, What city
> is like unto this great city!
>
> 19 And they cast dust on their heads, and cried, weeping and wailing,
> saying, Alas, alas that great city, wherein were made rich all that
> had ships in the sea by reason of her costliness! for in one hour is
> she made desolate.
>
> 20 Rejoice over her, thou heaven, and ye holy apostles and prophets;
> for God hath avenged you on her.
>
> 21 And a mighty angel took up a stone like a great millstone, and cast
> it into the sea, saying, Thus with violence shall that great city
> Babylon be thrown down, and shall be found no more at all.
>
> 22 And the voice of harpers, and musicians, and of pipers, and
> trumpeters, shall be heard no more at all in thee; and no craftsman,
> of whatsoever craft he be, shall be found any more in thee; and the
> sound of a millstone shall be heard no more at all in thee;
>
> 23 And the light of a candle shall shine no more at all in thee; and
> the voice of the bridegroom and of the bride shall be heard no more at
> all in thee: for thy merchants were the great men of the earth; for by
> thy sorceries were all nations deceived.
>
> 24 And in her was found the blood of prophets, and of saints, and of
> all that were slain upon the earth.

Comment: @Anton - It explains the origin of "Alas Babylon".

Comment: Indeed it does. I was merely surprised at your unusual prolixity.

Comment: Interesting that the angel threw a mighty stone into the sea. This might have been an explanation of a marine tsunami, but if so it must have been exceptional, reaching a height of 40 metres above sea level so far inland. Perhaps the reference is to exceptional flooding of the river that ran through Babylon.

Comment: @Anton One must consider that Revelation is mostly metaphor.

Comment: Yes, although tales such as the parting of the red sea may have root in real oceanographic phenomena such as the retreat of coastal waters in the upper parts of the Red Seas  in the early stage of a tsunami.

Comment: @Anton - One theory is that the Red Sea story is partly a typo -- the event occurred in a different body of water that was, at the time, known as the "Reed Sea".